# Cursor-controlled shape randomizing of RGBA color using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a function called mousemove that, when you move your cursor or mouse a trail of cirlces will  follow it like a snake. I am trying to figure how to completely randomize each circles color as you move it. How do you do that?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, give us some code and let us know what you are having troubles with.

Answer (score 0):

```
function randomColor() {
  var choices = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f'];
  var _color = "#"

  function _randomFromChoices(lst) {
    var _index = Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 );
    var _index = _index % lst.length;
    return lst[_index];
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    _color += _randomFromChoices(choices);
  }

  return _color;   

}
```

Is this what your are asking? Instead of assigning a specific color, use the above function that will generate a hex value randomly.